# PHP/Laravel 9 - How can i solve Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my laravel 9:

Call to undefined method App\Models\Country::id()

I use the Laravel framework version 9.x for programming.

This is my model code:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $table = 'countries';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'code'
    ];
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services\LogWriter;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class CountryController extends Controller
{

...
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Country  $country
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Country $country)
    {
        return view('countries.edit', compact('country'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Country  $country
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Country $country)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'code' => 'required|string|max:2|unique:countries',
        ]);
        $country->update($request->all());
        message_set("Successful! Country information has been changed.", 'success', 5);

        return redirect()->route('countries.index');
    }
...
```

I dont know why I get this error and would be glad if I could get any help.

Comment: Hey ! 

The controller looks fine,I think the issue is somewhere here -- countries.index

Can you share the code from index route?

Comment: Did you write `->id()` (a Method, with `()`) somewhere instead of `->id` (a Property, without `()`)? I don't see anywhere this code would trigger that error.

Comment: @AlexanderDyriavin this is a route Route::resource('countries', CountryController::class, ['except' => ['show']]);

Comment: Hello! Make sure you haven't removed the namespace declaration at the top of the model file `namespace App\Models;`

Comment: @njk18 The error suggests that it is there: `App\Models\Country::id()`

Comment: @TimLewis I'm sorry but that's the error message as I wrote it above and no, I don't have any reference to the ->id() method in the controller, nor to the ->id property

Comment: @njk18, he is right (Tim Lewis) the `namespace` is there

Comment: The error _should_ also show what file/line this is happening on, can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74777061/edit) to include that  information? You can usually find this in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: [2022-12-12 21:04:48] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Models\Country::id() {"view":{"view":"D:\\Projects\\laravel\\htdocs\\src\
esources\\views\\countries\\edit.blade.php"

Comment: There you go; your issue is in `edit.blade.php`; not in your Controller  Check if you're calling `->id()` in there, or otherwise, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74777061/edit) (like I already asked, but you posted it in the comments for some reason...) and add the contents of `edit.blade.php`

Comment: @TimLewis you are absolutely right, the problem was in the view

Comment: Wonderful! Lesson learned today, always check your error messages for the full information; assuming the problem was in the Controller can be right in a lot of cases, but Laravel's errors can also be triggered in a `.blade.php` view. Cheers!

Comment: If the problem has been solved then don't edit the word "Solved" into the question. Instead [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (unless the problem was trivial (such as a typo or not running the version of the code you shared) in which case you should delete the question instead). You can write your own answer if you solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned today, always check your error messages for the full information; assuming the problem was in the Controller can be right in a lot of cases, but Laravel's errors can also be triggered in a .blade.php view.

The problem was in the view `edit.blade.php`

"Check if you're calling ->id() in there"